# Shopware 6 add Custom Field to Admin Search

Tags: shopware, shopware6

How can I add a Product Custom Field to the Search in the Admin?

I could not find anything in the Shopware Doku, only for Custom Entitys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can add custom fields in the [search preferences of your profile](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/settings/Profilesettings#search-preferences) yet. You can however add fields by altering the corresponding entry in the table `user_config`.

For the entry to exist in the database you'll have to first make some changes in the search preferences of your profile.

Then find the entry for the correct user id in `user_config`. The column `value` contains the search preferences as json.

Edit that json to your liking, for example to add a custom field of a product to the searchable fields:

```json
[
    // ...
    {
        // ...
        "product": {
            // ...
            "customFields": {
                "the_technical_name_of_a_custom_field": {
                    "_score": 500,
                    "_searchable": true
                }
            },
            // ...
        },
        // ...
    },
    // ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help someone, but it's also necessary to define a `defaultSearchConfiguration` in a module registration.

Example of the `defaultSearchConfiguration`:

```js
const defaultSearchConfiguration = {
    _searchable: true,
    orderNumber: {
        _searchable: true,
        _score: 500
    }
};
```

Insert it in the module registration like:

```js
Shopware.Module.register(..., {
    ...
    navigation: [{
        ...
    }],

    defaultSearchConfiguration
}
```

I can't find anything about this in the documentation.