# I need a filter that searches for invoices. Is it possible to search by invoice number? Shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I need a filter that searches for invoices. This option is not available in search preferences.
Is it possible to search by invoice number?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the document number to the searchable fields in the [search preferences of your profile](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/settings/Profilesettings#search-preferences). When you're logged into the administration find `Your profile` in the bottom left and click it. Choose the tab `Search preferences` and check `Document number` under `Orders`.

Be aware that the option was only recently released with `6.4.15.0`. If you can't update for some reason you can also follow [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74347859/shopware-6-add-custom-field-to-admin-search/74348481#74348481) and add the field manually. In that case just  add the relevant part to the json like this:

```json
[
    {
        "order": {
            // ...
            "documents": {
                "config": {
                    "documentNumber": {
                        "_score": 80,
                        "_searchable": true
                    }
                }
            },
            // ...
        }
    },
    // ...
]
```